# Is it possible to use one .env file for a single repository?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, dotenv

The project I am working on has multiple node-modules within subfolders, and how I am structuring it now it seems dotenv is unable to locate the `.env` file in the root. This making the `process.env` variables `undefined`. Is there anywhere way I can make the environment variables accessible from all directories?

I have tried putting `require('dotenv').config();` at the top of the files, and even tried adding a script to run it in jest.config at the root. All results in `undefined`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit  ? May be you can share a diagram like how you have strcutured you folders.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clearly what did you want to do. But you can use [dotenv#path](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path) option to specify a path for `.env` file you want to load.